# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PostTag_Tag_TagId"

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using **Entity Framework 7 RC1** and I have the entities:

```
public class Post {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Title { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<PostTag> PostsTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<PostTag> PostsTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag {
  public Int32 PostId { get; set; }
  public Int32 TagId { get; set; }
  public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
  public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

The model configuration for these entities is the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {

  base.OnModelCreating(builder);

  builder.Entity<Post>(b => {

    b.ToTable("Posts");
    b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    b.Property(x => x.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
    b.Property(x => x.Title).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
  });

  builder.Entity<Tag>(b => {
    b.ToTable("Tags");
    b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    b.Property(x => x.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
    b.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
  });

  builder.Entity<PostTag>(b => {
    b.ToTable("PostsTags");
    b.HasKey(x => new { x.PostId, x.TagId });
    b.HasOne(x => x.Post).WithMany(x => x.PostsTags).HasForeignKey(x => x.PostId);
    b.HasOne(x => x.Tag).WithMany(x => x.PostsTags).HasForeignKey(x => x.TagId);
  });

}
```

I created the migration and the database. Then I tried to create a post:

```
  Context context = new Context();

  Post post = new Post {
    PostsTags = new List<PostTag> {
      new PostTag {
        Tag = new Tag { Name = "Tag name" }
      }
    },
    Title = "Post title"
  };

  context.Posts.Add(post);

  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And on save I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while updating the entries. 
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PostTag_Tag_TagId". 
The conflict occurred in database "TestDb", table "dbo.Tags", column 'Id'. 
The statement has been terminated.
```

Does anyone knows the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you don't need to explicitly declare your foreign keys in EF CodeFirst the framework will handle it for you. So remove these properties from the PostTag class

```
public Int32 PostId { get; set; }
public Int32 TagId { get; set; }
```

And then remove these two lines from your configuration then try the save again. You will probably need to update your DB Model before saving.

```
b.HasKey(x => new { x.PostId, x.TagId });
b.HasOne(x => x.Post).WithMany(x => x.PostsTags).HasForeignKey(x => x.PostId);
b.HasOne(x => x.Tag).WithMany(x => x.PostsTags).HasForeignKey(x => x.TagId);
```

Comment: But I want to have the FK on my model ... I always had since for a few queries it is really useful ... And BTW I never had this problem with EF 6 ...

Comment: In that case you have to make your foreign keys nullable. In your example your PostId will be 0 which is breaking the FK constraint as i'm guessing you don't have a 0 as a PostId in the DB.

Comment: I suspect it is the composite key that is making it error out b.HasKey(x => new { x.PostId, x.TagId }); Do you really need this? Why not have a PK for this class.

Comment: Because this is just a relation table and not need for PK which is completely valid in SQL ... But it is strange because this exact configuration works in EF 6 ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems. Here's the solution I came up with. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496087/entity-framework-7-cascading-inserts) SO question helped me a lot.

First of all, add a `public DbSet<Tag> Tags {get; set;}` to yout `Context` class if it's missing.

Then modify the post creation as follows

```
Context context = new Context();
var tmpTag = new Tag { Name = "Tag name" } //add the tag to the context
context.Tags.Add(tmpTag);

Post post = new Post {
    PostsTags = new List<PostTag>(), // initialize the PostTag list
    Title = "Post title"
};    
context.Posts.Add(post);

var postTag = new PostTag() {Post = post, Tag = tag}; // explicitly initialize the PostTag AFTER addig both Post and Tag to context
post.PostTags.Add(postTag); // add PostTag to Post

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Explictly adding both `post` and `tag` to `context.Posts` and `context.Tags` before attempting to create the `PostTag` object allows EF to correctly manage the IDs while writing to the underlying DB.

For the sake of completeness, after solving this part of the many-to-many relationship management, I'm currently struggling with CascadeDelete Entity Framework Core (EF7), but that's a different story.

Comment: It's incredible that we still need work-arounds for this in a *release candidate*. EF should be able to figure out the insert order itself.