# Insert into the junction table in EF 7

Tags: ef-code-first, many-to-many, relational-database, entity-framework-core

Since the many-to-many relationship is not supported in Entity Framework 7 yet,

I'm following work around in this [link](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many).

Here is the code from the link above:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
            .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

**Question**

How can I associate a `Tag` to a `Post`? 
In other words how can I add a row to the junction table?

Comment: Did you try something like `MyPost.PostTags.Add(new PostTag(){ ... })`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35798149/6011874) where the method I came up with is explained.

Create your `Tag` instance and add it to Tags. Do the same with the `Post` instance, initializing its PostTags navigation property, and add it to `Posts`.
Then create the `PostTag` instance, initializing it with both `Post` and `Tag` instances.
Finally call `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync` methods.

This will allow EF to properly manage ID properties before writing all the involved entities to the underlying DB.